# Distributing beta iPhone app without UUIDs

Tags: iphone, ad-hoc-distribution

At first I thought that in order to do an ad-hoc deployment of a beta iPhone app, you had to burn the device's UUID of the target user into the app.  (I use TestFlight to do it)

But a few days ago I came across http://retraceapp.com/, and you're able to download their app straight from their website.

I did get several security warnings, but I didn't think this was possible at all.  Does someone know how they did this?

**Update**: The link is no longer available on the website.

Comment: Just tried it and indeed it works. It is most definitely an enterprise account using ADHOC sign. The account will be banned soon unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a Enterprise account app, which actually is not allowed to be distributed outside a company.

One can find the key `ProvisionsAllDevices` set to true in its provisioning profile. See here about that [ProvisionsAllDevices vs ProvisionedDevices in embedded.mobileprovision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763977/provisionsalldevices-vs-provisioneddevices-in-embedded-mobileprovision)

Comment: Interesting: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/  That makes sense.  If I'm developing an app for one specific business, I don't necessarily want to put it on the App Store.  This would let me send it straight to that business without getting Apple involved.  Nice...  :)   Thanks @epatel!

Comment: @Antony You should not use an enterprise account for that. Use the B2B store instead. edit: https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

Comment: Interesting.. didn't know about that either.  Thanks @MikeWeller!

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the Co-Founders of Retrace. We used an Enterprise developer account.
Here's a link that explains more.

[IOS Enterprise Distribution Through OTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439127/ios-enterprise-distribution-through-ota)

Apple contacted us after about 2 weeks and forced us to shut down the link and move to the App Store.

Comment: Thanks for the word of caution, @Austin!