# how can I offline distribute ios app

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there anyway that I can distribute my IOS application offline? I need to put my ipa file on a local network and allow my internal customers download and install them.

I was read about Apple Enterprise program but is it completely offline? and i heard it need us to submit all devices to apple!

is there any other way to install ios app completely offline on public devices?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

Well offline. Not really. Unless you would prefer jailbreak.

You have 3 options:

1. Distribute via AppStore (free, but everybody can download)
2. Distribute via AppStore B2B (volume pricing, not available for all countries)
3. Via Enterprise Setup
4. Adhoc

**ad. 1 & 4**

Im sure you you thought of these options.

**ad. 2**

Distribute via AppStore, https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

> Custom apps are distributed privately to authorized Volume Purchase Program for Business members that you identify in iTunes Connect. Customers sign in and purchase their apps on the Volume Purchase Program store.

Im not sure about option 2, but it **might** be that Apple will still be reviewing the app. If you choose Enterprise dist. Apple **will not review** your app. and you need to setup your own infrastructure.

**ad. 3**

```
/* this is on a per company basis, you can't setup your 
   own enterprise account and start distribution 
   to *different* companies. */
```

I have implemented this for a customer. They have a enterprise subscription. Then they invited me as a team member. I can sign the IPA file with the correct certs.

We choose (< 30 devices)to install via a webpage. Its has a install link. There a 2 files you need. A PLIST and the Binary (IPA). The PLISt files contains the URL to the IPA file. Once i place a update, they need to manual install this on each device.

If you like you can also just type the plist link directly in safari, or make "app bookmark".

You can push the app to all devices (Mobile Device Management (MDM)), but (as far as i know) you need a more advanced setup. I never looked into this.

*Since iOS 6 the files needs to be server from a HTTPS connection! I have setup a self sign certificate (since the server is running on a LAN), and we then installed the HTTPS certs on each device. You could bypass the certs issue by putting the files on something like dropbox (or by official certs)*

Comment: Enterprise distribution is limited to employees of the company.

Comment: @zaph You are right if you mean the OP can't setup his own enterprise server and start distribution to different companies.  For that i think B2B is the way to go. But depending on his customers and type of relation he has, they could get their own enterprise subscription, then he needs to sign a IPA for each of his customers. All depends on quantity i think.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to distribute iOS apps:

- The app store, that is even appropriate for apps that are only useful to a small number of users. You can limit usefulness to known users.
- TestFlight but that has time and user limitations.
- AppStore B2B
- Ad Hoc distribution but like TestFlight has time and user limitations.
- Enterprise but apps can only be distributed to your company's employees.

Any other method opens the door to malicious apps and/or apps that do not properly support parental controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ad-hoc distribution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW4).

Basically you need a provisioning profile that will include all the devices you need to run tests on, use that provisioning profile when making a build, and then generate an `.ipa` (if you don't know how you can find some tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499125/how-to-create-ipa-file-using-xcode)).

The users that will want to test the new build can download it from your network share and can install it via iTunes on their iPhone/iPad/iPod (details about this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720764/install-ipa-with-itunes-12)).

Just make sure to have all the devices added to your provisioning profile, otherwise the installation will failed. Also keep in mind that you are allowed to add at most 100 devices in your developer account.

Comment: Note that there is a time limit on an ad-hoc app.