# How to run the project on device with AdHoc certificates in iOS?

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

**I know that we can run the project with the developer certificates if phone is connected to the MAC.**

I am working on getting push notifications after the application has build with the AdHoc Provisional Profiles.

After the each and every change in the project I have to create build and upload it to any ipa sharing server like [betafamily](https://betafamily.com/supersend/).

I know that for the each change we have to create the IPA file.

After the each upload I have to download it and run on the device to check that push notifications with the AdHoc.

**Any one have idea? :** How to run the project on device with AdHoc certificates in iOS? (without every-time upload and download the ipa because ipa size is too big)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As par my knowledge i don't think that possible to test application with any of certificate that your changes directly reflect without creating new IPA.

Because each change is need to be re-build again and you also need to re-generate its archive and IPA.

If you notice that when you upload app on app-store and is there is some coding related issue then in resolve-center said need to upload binary again.

So for testing each change you need to re-create IPA for sure.

Comment: I know that for the each change we have to create the IPA file. I am asking that is there any way to taste that ipa directly with device ?

Comment: What do you mean by directly. You need to install IPA by iTunes or OTA like you posted link or www.diawi.com

Comment: Ok, that I understood. I am doing it via betafamily. how to do it via iTunes?

Comment: Hi @AshishKakkad, I have posted an answer that explain how to install it by iTunes.

Comment: You can find the way of install IPA using iTunes by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720764/install-ipa-with-itunes-12 and video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dib1HSTk1dA

Answer (score 1):

You can install your AdHoc generated ipa directly in your device. Just drag the ipa to iTunes icon and sync your device. A new version of your application will be available and you will be able to test your Push Notifications right away.

Comment: Thanks, to you too. :)

Answer (score 0):

One more easy and bast way. Please select AdHoc Provisioning Profile and select iOS Device and Run your app. Display your splash screen and close your app but your code is execute. Reopen your app and it's work fine.

Comment: Thanks, From your solution the app updated as we have updated in Xcode.