# How to send iOS app to a client

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

We developed an iOS app for a client in XCode.
Now we want to upload the app to their account.
In Android this is dead simple, you just build an apk file and send it to them.  Then they can upload it to Google Play or any other service.
iOS seems horrifically complicated.

The client is not technical, so sending them the source code and having them deploy the app from XCode is not an option.

We have been able to create them an app in our own iTunesConnect account and have them test the app using TestFlight.

They have created an iTunesConnect account, and were able to add our account to their "team" and we can now see the app they created, but we cannot upload a build to it from XCode.  Not sure exactly what is required, how to upload to the other team, or if their is an easier way?

Answer (score 5):

My first guess, if you were given a technical role on your clients iTunes Account, you cannot use Xcode to upload the build.  You have to be of admin role for that.

Use Xcode to export an IPA file.  Then use the 'Application Loader' to submit to your clients account.

Also be sure you're added correctly on iTunes Connect, because only in the developer account are you added to the 'team'.  In iTunes Connect you are added as a 'user' and assigned a 'role'.

**EDIT:**

So there's not any confusion: There are two parts to this process, code signing, and uploading to iTunes.  You need to be on your clients Developer Account team to properly code sign the app, with a distribution certificate and App Store provisioning profile created via their account.  Once you have a properly code-signed IPA with those credentials, then you need to upload to their iTunes Connect account in the manner I described above.

Comment: Or send the export ipa to the client and have them use Application Loader to upload the app to their account.

Comment: @Frankie your ans is correct but can we create IPA without any provisional profile and certificate of client appstore account And Without Team selection in XCode?

Comment: @ashmi123 I assumed the OP had already signed the app with the correct credentials since they were invited to the clients 'team', but my assumption may be wrong.  I'll add a bit more detail to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Did you create certification from dev portal ? If yes, you have added the account to xcode settings and follow the steps from 3. If you did nothing, please do these step by step:

1. Create certificate from here: https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203808748-iOS-Creating-a-Distribution-Certificate-and-p12-File
2. Use the certificate : http://sites.injoit.com/knowledge-base/for-developers/certificates/how-to-use-distribution-certificate
3. Create adhoc mobile proviosion to create ipa for client: http://www.manyfriends.com/wiki/iphone/index.php/Create_an_ad-hoc_provisioning_profile
4. [How to create IPA in Xcode 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970741/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6)

Now upload the ipa through https://www.diawi.com/ and get the ipa link to be installed from iphone safari. Send the link to client.

Otherwise, send the ipa file directly to client. Then it needs to be installed from itunes. Follow this: [Install IPA with iTunes 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720764/install-ipa-with-itunes-12)

Hope these will help you!

Comment: I did all above but still getting"Unable to install xyz" - "This app cannot be install because its integrity couldnt be verified". Not sure what to do. Do client need to enable developer mode on?

Answer (score 4):

One of the best way is https://www.diawi.com/

It will create a link of that app, and client can install directly from safari or any web browser.

For this just you need to create a provisional profile with added client UDID.

Than just archive your app take that archived file(find IPA) copy this file.

paste anywhere in your machine and zip this file. open diawi website upload that zip file. it will create a link for that app, from that link client can install the app.....

Answer (score 3):

if you are troubling with Test Flight and you want to test with development profile then here it is one url which help you to send build to your client, just drag here your ipa file it will automatically generate one url and you can send to your client

https://www.diawi.com/

How to install in device ?

- Just click on that url it will automatically started to get download.

Note:

Development profile must contain device id (udid) of client.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. **Sending build for testing**

After creating build (development or enterprise) you can upload that
    build to this online tool [Install on Air](https://www.installonair.com). And it will generate
    one short URL for you. And it's free service.

You can send that URL to your client or testers and they can open that URL in iOS Safari browser and it will install in one click.

Alternatively you can use Diawi as well but there are some limitations in free account.

2. **Upload Build to App Store**

Create an iOS distribution provisioning profile and distribution certificate.

Use that certificate to sign the build. Then goto Product menu on Xcode and click Archive. That will allow you to upload build to App store. You will have to login with the apple account to do that. And also make sure that instead of simulator you have selected Generic iOS Device before doing archive.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem you have to take the client APP Store credential because without that you cannot make build to create IPA file.

So first just take the Credential for Appstore account then process for the Certificates and provisional profile and then just upload through APPlication loader or from XCode. You can ask to client for Change in password for APpstore account after successful submission on appStore.

Answer (score 1):

For create and send link of ipa of ios app follow perfact ways

```
1)upto 100mb ipa use this link to create ipa link :
```

https://www.diawi.com/

```
2)upload any size ipa and create link(Free,paid plan)
```

https://betafamily.com/supersend

```
3)upload any size ipa and create link(Free,paid plan)
```

https://www.installonair.com/

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion the best option is to upload your distribution build ( ipa ) to this website : http://putul.io

1. It will generate a link to share
2. Share link with your team and clients

It supports ipa and apk file upto 100MB.
I use this very often..I find it pretty fast for uploads and download ( for installation)

Cheers

Answer (score -2):

It's not so difficult, Here is the guide for you:

1. Open the App Store on your iPhone, iPod touch, or iPad. Alternatively, you could open up iTunes on your computer.
2. Go to the app you want to send, for example [Vidmate app](http://vidmateappz.com/)
3. In the app's preview page, look to the top right on the iPad or the bottom of the page on an iPhone or iPod touch to find the "Gift This App" link.
4. Log in with your Apple ID (your account for iTunes) and enter in your name, recipient's name, and recipient's email.
5. You'll get a chance to review the app gift before buying it. Once you do, your account will be charged, the app will be sent to your gift recipient, and you'll get a receipt.