# How can I install an iOS app in iOS device without Macbook?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-app-group

I have got an iOS app to be tested as a Beta user but it is placed at some location of Google drive. I don't have Macbook. How can that app be installed in an iOS device

Comment: You can try old version of iTunes. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720764/install-ipa-with-itunes-12

Answer (score -1):

At first, make sure your device's UDID is included in the provisioning profile which was used to build the ipa file. If it is, you can upload the ipa file to the third party services and get a download link:
1. https://www.diawi.com
2. https://hockeyapp.net
3. http://www.deployninja.com
4. https://appho.st